# Some Python objects were not bound to checkpointed values

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, object-detection-api

I am trying to get started with Tensorflow 2.0 [Object Detection API](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection). I have gone through the installation following [the official tutorial](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html) and I pass all the tests. However, I keep getting an error message that I don't understand when I try to run the main module. This is how I run it:

```
python model_main_tf2.py --model_dir=ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn_640x640_coco17_tpu-8 --pipeline_config_path=ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn_640x640_coco17_tpu-8/pipeline.config
```

This is the beginning of the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "model_main_tf2.py", line 113, in <module>
    tf.compat.v1.app.run()
  File "/home/hd/hd_hd/hd_rs239/.conda/envs/jan_tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 40, in run
    _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
  File "/home/hd/hd_hd/hd_rs239/.conda/envs/jan_tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 299, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "/home/hd/hd_hd/hd_rs239/.conda/envs/jan_tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 250, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "model_main_tf2.py", line 110, in main
    record_summaries=FLAGS.record_summaries)
  File "/home/hd/hd_hd/hd_rs239/.conda/envs/jan_tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/object_detection/model_lib_v2.py", line 569, in train_loop
    unpad_groundtruth_tensors)
  File "/home/hd/hd_hd/hd_rs239/.conda/envs/jan_tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/object_detection/model_lib_v2.py", line 383, in load_fine_tune_checkpoint
    ckpt.restore(checkpoint_path).assert_existing_objects_matched()
  File "/home/hd/hd_hd/hd_rs239/.conda/envs/jan_tf2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/util.py", line 791, in assert_existing_objects_matched
    (list(unused_python_objects),))
AssertionError: Some Python objects were not bound to checkpointed values, likely due to changes in the Python program: [SyncOnReadVariable:{
  0: <tf.Variable 'conv2_block1_0_bn/moving_variance:0' shape=(256,) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.,
```

In the pipeline.config, I specify a checkpoint like this:

```
  fine_tune_checkpoint: "ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn_640x640_coco17_tpu-8/checkpoint/ckpt-0"
```

These are the contents of `ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn_640x640_coco17_tpu-8/checkpoint/` :

```
checkpoint  
ckpt-0.data-00000-of-00001  
ckpt-0.index
```

I have searched Google but couldn't find any answer. In [this issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/8399), the suggested solution is outdated (the code they suggest to replace is not there anymore).

**Question:** What is the problem and how can I solve it?

I am doing this on a server with CentOS Linux 7. I am using Python 3.7. I am new to Tensorflow so please if I am missing any important information, let me know.

Comment: Most likely a bug in latest tensorflow 2.3.0

Comment: I meet the same bug in TensorFlow 2.2.0 when export my custom model.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

From the file name you provided (ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn_640x640_coco17_tpu-8), I can see you are trying to work with an object detection task. Therefore, in your pipeline.config file change this line:

```
fine_tune_checkpoint_type: "classification"
```

To:

```
fine_tune_checkpoint_type: "detection"
```

This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 4):

For me it was usefull to check type of feature extractor. I change `type: "mobilenet_v2"` to `type: "mobilenet_v2_fpn_sep_conv"` in pipeline.config. And its start working.

Answer (score 1):

I've been running into the same issue trying to get MobileNet & CenterNet to work.
First of all: this error seems to be dependend on which Tensorflow version you are using. In my case, a colleague used TF 2.2 and it worked, whereas my TF 2.10 threw this error!

However, there are reasons why you would not want to downgrade. If you are training a custom dataset and **don't need the pre-trained COCO weights**, there is an easy workaround:

Simply don't use the fine tune checkpoint which you downloaded from the Model Zoo. To do so, in `pipeline.config` delete the line `fine_tune_checkpoint: "your_path"` and this error will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error but for me, it was a simple copy&paste mistake. My `fine_tune_checkpoint` pointed to `faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_640x640_coco17_tpu-8/checkpoint/ckpt-0` instead of `faster_rcnn_resnet50_v1_640x640_coco17_tpu-8/checkpoint/ckpt-0`